# Android JetpackCompose spacer with weight and min height

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a `Column` that has a modifier with `verticalScroll()` on it that fills the screen height. There are elements at the top and bottom of the column that have a third element centred between them using two spacers with weights of 1.0.

Occasionally elements may be added that make the column longer than the screen and activate the scroll. At that point the spacers shrink to nothing since they no longer need to fill space to fit the screen.

I've tried adding a height attribute in conjunction with the weight but that seems to have no effect. How do I have spacers fill space while also constraining to a height minimum?

Code:

```kotlin
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxWidth()
    .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
    .fillMaxHeight(),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
) {
    PotentialOptionalElements()
    PageHeader()
    Spacer(Modifier.weight(1.0f))
    PageContent()
    Spacer(Modifier.weight(1.0f))
    PageFooter()
}
```

Comment: There is a `Modifier.heightIn(min = 16.dp)`, did you try this?

Comment: I did, it doesn't seem to play nice with the weight modifier on the same spacer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Barring other options - The following works:

```kotlin
Spacer(Modifier.weight(1.0f))
Spacer(Modifier.height(16.dp))
```

Would however still prefer a solution that uses a single spacer

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this combination of modifiers works:

```
Spacer(modifier = Modifier
            .weight(1f)
            .requiredHeight(16.dp))
```